# Linguex bad spacing between number and examples with certain values above 99 when using old style numbers

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, linguistics, linguex

When using `linguex` example numbering packing, if I use `\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}` with xetex or luatex, then with certain example numbers exceeding 99, there is no spacing between the example number and the text:

[image]

Minimal example (with ellipsis of actual repeated examples necessary to push numbering over 99):

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt] 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle} 
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}    
\ex. Hello, world! Quit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

....

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

Aside from not using oldstyle numbers, is there a way around this?  I tried playing with different values for linguex's `\Exlabelwidth`, but none of the values seemed to make any difference.

Comment: FYI, you can use `\setcounter{ExNo}{98}` before the first example to make the first example (99), rather than actually putting that many examples in. You can play with this value to see that many of the three-digit numerals ending in 0, 2, 4, 6, and 9 have this problem.

Comment: I tried explicitly using the old-style numerals in `\Exlabelwidth`, but that didn't help either: `\newfontfamily{\oldnums}{Junicode}[Numbers={OldStyle}] \AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\Exlabelwidth}{\oldnums (999)}}`.

Comment: This is a font problem, not a `linguex` problem.  Changing the font to e.g. Linux Libertine O, or Minion Pro there is no issue.

Comment: Linux Libertine seems to work okay, though Cardo has similar problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The source of the problem

The problem is caused by the fact the Junicode font has true proportional old style numbers, whereas some other fonts have, both, fixed width old style numbers and proportional old style numbers.  The `linguex` package sets an internal length that is a multiple of the smallest width digit in the current font.  The smallest width digit in the Junicode font is the `1`, and this turns out to be too small relative to some of the other number widths in the font, so that the calculation for the label spacing is thrown off.

We can see this in action by comparing the width of the Junicode old style numbers  with the Linux Libertine font which has both sorts. With the proportional old style numbers the problem arises, but with the fixed width old style numbers it doesn't. (Thanks to Jason for pointing this out.)

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\Junicode[Numbers=OldStyle]{Junicode}
\newfontfamily\LibertineFixed[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\LibertineProportional[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{linguex}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newlength{\tmplen}

\newcommand{\displaywidthof}[1]
    {\settowidth{\tmplen}{#1}\parbox{.8in}{#1: \the\tmplen}}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {Junicode,LibertineProportional,LibertineFixed}{
\csname\x\endcsname

\x

\foreach \y in {0,...,9}{
\displaywidthof{\y}
}

\setcounter{ExNo}{99}

\ex. XXX.


\ex. YYY.

}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### The solution to the problem

Luckily there is a way to fix this: some undocumented commands in the package allow you to set widths for the label spacing.  The author of `linguex` hints at the problem in the documentation

> I hope that fonts are cooperative by keeping the difference between
>   the width of digits minimal. Otherwise you might experience weird
>   behavior of `\Exlabelwidth`

In fact, I helped solve a similar problem with another font which was the original reason for this code.  The command:

```
\philabeldefault
```

does the following:

```
\renewcommand{\philarge}{4\mindigitwidth}
\renewcommand{\philmiddle}{3\mindigitwidth}
\renewcommand{\philsmall}{2\mindigitwidth}}
```

Where the numbers here are the multipliers for 100's, 10's and 1's respectively. Notice that the multipliers are different for each set, which will result in non-uniform spacing.

So one way to fix the problem is to just change the multiplier for the `\philarge` length:

```
\renewcommand{\philarge}{4.5\mindigitwidth}
```

works fine.

However, you can also give a fixed length for all three lengths using the command:

```
\phlabelwidth
```

This is perhaps a better solution.  So setting

```
\phlabelwidth{1.4em}
```

solves the problem nicely.

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt] 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle} 
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\usepackage{linguex}
\phlabelwidth{1.4em}

\begin{document} 

\ex. Hello, world! Quit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\setcounter{ExNo}{9}
\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.


\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\setcounter{ExNo}{99}
\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\ex. Hello, world! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: What is it about the font that would cause this?  Do you have any thoughts? (As above, at least Cardo also has similar problems.)

Comment: @emacsomancer I've added a detailed explanation of the problem.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation & solution!

Comment: Great explanation! The above widths are right for the monospaced old-style numerals in Linux Libertine O, but if you use `\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Linux Libertine O}` you get varying widths, resulting in the same problem that Junicode and Cardo have.

Comment: @JasonZentz Thanks for pointing that out.  I've changed the test example to reflect the two behaviours with a single font, which makes the example much cleaner.